# Postgres foreign key with ON DELETE SET NULL for only some of its columns

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.4

I have added a (new) 2nd foreign key to a table `a`. Its 1st foreign key is optional, hence the constraint `ON DELETE SET NULL` on the foreign key. The 2nd foreign key is mandatory, hence the (new) constraints `NOT NULL` on `a1` and `a2` and (new) the constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key. The 2nd foreign key also consists of a subset of the columns for the 1st foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  a0 INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  -- other columns
  a1 INT NOT NULL,
  a2 INT NOT NULL,
  a3 INT,
  a4 INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (a1, a2)         REFERENCES b ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (a1, a2, a3, a4) REFERENCES c ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

The problem that I run into is that I can now no longer `DELETE FROM c`, since this invalidates the `NOT NULL` constraints on `a1` and `a2`. What I would like to happen in the case of such deletes is for `a1, a2` to remain unmodified and for `a3, a4` to be set to `NULL`. Is there a concise syntax (more concise than with an [extra](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108916/51062) `DELETE` trigger) for defining a constraint that achieves this?

Comment: If `a1`, `a2` should remain unmodified then they are no more foreign keys, so the constraint is no more valid. Or I am missing something?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I've added the table's primary key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no way for the `CASCADE` action to set only some of the columns to `NULL`. So the only options I see would be:

- have all the 4 columns defined as `NULL` and use `ON DELETE SET NULL` action. Seems like this is not an option in your case.
- add another table to hold this relationship (where all the columns are not nullable) and use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
- a trigger.
- create a procedure (function in Postgres) to handle deletions of table `c`. The function would first modify the columns (`c`,`d`) in table `a` and then delete from table `c`. Then you have to make sure that all users/applications use this function and do not directly delete from table `c`.

Comment: I'll probably go with a trigger then.